# Extracting Outlook Contact Information with VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, contacts

I am trying to extract email addresses from the contact information section of a contact in Outlook, however, I cannot access the same data that is displayed when right clicking on a contact and navigating to `Outlook Properties > E-Mail Addresses`.

[image: Contact Information]

How might I access this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

```
ContactItem.Email1Address
```

> Returns or sets a String representing the e-mail address of the first
>   e-mail entry for the contact. Read/write.

[via MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff860936.aspx)

[Gregthatcher.com](http://www.gregthatcher.com/Scripts/VBA/Outlook/GetListOfContacts.aspx) has a report script that can be modified for this task.  Basically you `Set ContactFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)` and then loop through `For Each currentItem In ContactFolder.Items`, check for class `Class = olContact` then get the `currentItem.Email1Address`.

Comment: I used that but it returned empty strings. Looking through the Locals Window in Visual Basic Editor, all the email parameters had empty values.

Comment: @Thanasis are any of the other contactItem attributes populated?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question @C8H10N4O2. When to be populated?

Answer (score 1):

What you have above is not a contact, this is a GAL address entry. The data in the screenshot is stored in the PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F` ).

The script below will display proxy addresses of the EX sender of the currently selected message in Outlook:

```
Set msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set vSender = msg.Sender
vProxyAddresses = vSender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F")
For Index = LBound(vProxyAddresses) To UBound(vProxyAddresses)
  MsgBox vProxyAddresses(Index)
Next
```

Comment: But what if I don't have a message? What I initially wanted to do is this: The username of the user in the Excel is the same with the username in the credential of Windows. Furthermore, this username can be found in the list of the emails I have attached in the screenshot in the form 'username@company.com' .I want to use the username of the user in the Excel, find which contact has this email in the outlook and retrieve the name of the user. Is this possible without having to search in emails' senders?

Comment: In that case call Application.Session.CreateRecipient passing the name to be resolved, call Recipient.Resolve. If it returns true, use the Recipient.AddressEntry object.

Comment: I am not pretty sure if I will be able to do what you said. However, I will try that tomorrow at work and I will tell you my outcome. Btw, I found some of your comments in [Can't get SMTP address of contact that shares email address of an Exchange user](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/cant-get-smtp-address-of-contact-that-shares-email-address-of-an-exchange-user.3055223/)

I will have a look at this too.

Comment: According to Microsoft MSDN [Map a Display Name to an E-mail Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868500.aspx) the parameter in the 'CreateRecipient' part is a name. However, the only thing that I know is one of the smtp emails which has a pattern like 'k012345@conpany.com' and I am looking for the name of the account which has this email in the list shown in the screenshot. Can I still use the method you suggested and put as a parameter in the 'CreateRecipient' the 'k012345@conpany.com' ?

Comment: Exchange provider will resolve an SMTP address to a GAL user. It can also use display name and alias (logon) name.

Comment: I wrote the following code:<br/>

 `Set oRecip = olA.Session.CreateRecipient("K0123@comp.com")  
 oRecip.Resolve  
 
 If oRecip.Resolved Then  
       Select Case oRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType`  

The last line return the value 30. Based on the code for MSDN which I have attached in my previous comment, it can only recognize 0 and 1.

Comment: 30 is olSmtpAddressEntry. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868214.aspx

Comment: Yes, correct, I found that also in the `Locals Window`. However, is there any way to find the name of the account that has that smtp email?

Comment: Name as in "Exchange GAL user name"? Does the SMTP address you pass to CreateRecipient come from an Exchange server used in the current profile?

Comment: I want to retrieve `Thanasis` when I search for `k0123@comp.com` . The SMTP address is one of the many addresses which are included in the attached photo. It is not the primary SMTP address.

Comment: Does Outlook correctly resolve that address if you type it in the To edit box and hit Ctrl+K?

Comment: No, unfortunately it can't give any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean? That there is no autocomplete dropdown? That tis not what I meant. Type the address, hit Ctrk+K.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my prolonged delay but I was away from work and I couldn't try what you suggested. What I meant is that when I type k0123 in the To edit box and hit Ctr+K then the Check Names window pops up and there are no Suggestions for what I have written. It says "Microsoft Office Outlook does not recognize "k0123".